# Error Handling: set_error_handler() expects the argument (errorHandler) to be a valid callback

Tags: php, error-handling

I've got a PHP form with several lines of code.

Now I want to log errors in the database.

I'm trying to do this by the following code:

```
<?php
set_error_handler("errorHandler");

//The following line produces an error for testing
echo $notexist;

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo "error detected";
}
?>
```

Unfortunately PHP throws an error and I can't find out how to fix it:

"set_error_handler() expects the argument (errorHandler) to be a valid callback"

I think I defined the callback, didn't I?

Comment: You cannot insert an array [var_user_id]  as sql field value.

Comment: Where is `function errorHandler` defined and where do you call `set_error_handler("errorHandler");`? Do you have to `include` the file that contains the definition of `function errorHandler`? If yes: Do you use `include` or `require`?

Comment: @Ravi: I corrected the code for deifinition of the sql-string. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jörg: You're welcome :) Is your problem resolved?

Comment: @Ravi: No, not yet. But to focus on the main issue, I removed the SQL-string from the code example above (corrected SQL-string: $strSQL = "INSERT INTO errorlog (created_user_cap_id, severity, message, filename, lineno, time) VALUES ("."'".[var_user_id]."','". $errno."','".$errstr."','".$errfile."','".$errline."','".NOW().")";

Answer (score 5):

If the function is in a namespace you need to put the fully qualified name of the function (including the namespace).

For example:

```
 <?php

    namespace MyNamespace;

    set_error_handler("MyNamespace\t_errorHandler");

    echo $notexist;

    function t_errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        echo "error detected";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is correct with the assumption that the function is in a namespace while op didn't mention anything like that. also you will have to escape the \ since the double quote will interpolate \t to tab.